# Remove two items in RecyclerView instancely, the last item appear duplicated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a function that remove two rows of my `RecyclerView` (writen in Kotlin) that contain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I expect to have remain 1,4,5,6,7,8

```
fun remItemFromList() {
    itemList.remove(1)
    notifyItemRemoved(1)
    itemList.remove(1)
    notifyItemRemoved(1)
}
```

Upon execute the function, the last item i.e. double 8 appear, as per illustrated in the GIF below. Why, and how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: I would say that `notifyItemRemoved(1)` is asynchronous, so 2 calls with the same parameters are basically duplicates, and the recycler view only ever considers that 1 item was removed. I suggest trying `notifyItemRemoved(2)` to use the previous indexation of the item

Comment: You might want to use `DiffUtil` if you want to refresh multiple items: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to achieve what I want using DiffUtil. More elaboration in https://medium.com/@elye.project/simultaneous-insertion-and-removal-of-recyclerview-with-animation-f9e1800a3dd0#.3evndq4is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notifyItemRangeRemoved` :
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRangeRemoved(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Check below one to get helpful and it will remove 2nd and 3rd position:

```
fun remItemFromList() {
    itemList.remove(1)
    notifyItemRemoved(1)
    itemList.remove(1)
    notifyItemRemoved(1)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(1, arrData.size - 2)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun remItemFromList(positionFirst: Int, positionSecond: Int) {
    itemList.remove(positionFirst)
    itemList.remove(positionSecond)
    notifyitemChanged()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To refresh multiple items call notifydatasetchanged() method.